# Why does Android Studio freeze up in full screen mode?

Tags: android-studio, fullscreen

Recently I installed Android Studio (which worked perfectly on Windows), but it locks up when I switch to full screen mode and accepts no keyboard input, so each time I need to login using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> and kill all processes by running `kill -9 -1`.

So, any idea why it's happening and how to get rid of it? Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: Well, I've only 4 gigs of RAM

Comment: FWIW, I can get Android Studio to work reasonably well on a device that has only 2GB RAM by closing all other programs, especially RAM-hogging browsers. Admittedly, since I don't know anything without the internet, that's not very practical...